# Access all submodels from a ActiveRecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to write something like this

```
User.groups.members.addresses
```

What I need is an array of all addresses which User has access to. If User is in two groups, each group has 2 unique members with unique addresses I want an array of 4 addresses

Using Ruby on rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a scope to your address model, you just need to add some joins in there. Haven't tested this but it should be on the right track.

```
class Address 
  scope :by_user, -> user { joins(:member).joins(:group).where(user: {id: user.id})}}
end
```

usage:

```
Address.by_user(@user)
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain further how it works? Can't seem to find any good documentation regarding joins

Comment: It's a SQL concept that ActiveRecord makes easy to use: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables